# What is the "name" next to [[Prototype]]? Why does the use of inheritance show the name of the parent constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to understand what the name next to the `[[Prototype]]` property means. At first I thought it would be the "class" name (the constructor) of the object (thus, `[[Prototype]]` Object would refer to `Object.prototype`). However, the following example puzzled me. I don't understand what the name refers to.

I googled everywhere.

[image]

Comment: The name refers to the parent class. Every object inherits from `Object`

Comment: I just uploaded an image. It is on the console

Comment: It means that `Teacher` inherits from the `Person` prototype

Comment: Why in Object.prototype shows it as [[Prototype]] Object ?

Comment: For completion, what [JavaScript engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) is this? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: Related: https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance

Comment: Because `Object` is the root of the prototype hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry, it's still confusing to me. Assuming that in `[[Prototype]] Name` the "Name" corresponds to the parent constructor, and that in Object.prototype you see `[[Prototype]] Object` because it is the root of the prototype hierarchy, I don't understand why for Array.prototype we see `[[Prototype]] Array`. Perhaps "Name" is the parent constructor for class inheritance cases (I know it's syntactic sugar), but for direct prototype use cases the "Name" corresponds to the constructor itself?